# Does every complete logic extend propositional logic?

Tags: logic

Predicate logic extends propositional logic. Is this also the case for every other complete logic?

Comment: What do you mean with "extend" ? The language of predicate logic is more "expressive" than that of prop logic, of course, and thus it can prove "logic laws" like: $\forall x Px \rightarrow Py$ which are not *tautologies*...

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the standard accounts of predicate logic do not include propositional variables of any kind, and so I don't think it is correct to say that predicate logic "extends" propositional logic, if one takes this to mean, in particular, that the assertions of propositional logic are valid assertions in predicate logic. They are not. In this sense, the answer to your question is negative.